# reactjs jest jQuery is not defined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I am using jest to test my reactJS component.
In my reactJS component, I need to use jquery UI, so I added this in the component:

```
var jQuery = require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui/ui/core');
require('jquery-ui/ui/draggable');
require('jquery-ui/ui/resizable');
```

And it worked fine. But, now, I need to used jest to do testing, but I immediately meet this issue when I load the component into testutils,

```
Test suite failed to run
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

Has anyone met this issue if you are using jQuery in your app?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800122/uncaught-referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined-with-create-react-app/

Comment: Have you tried `window.$ = require('jquery');`?

Answer (score 53):

You can add jQuery dependency in your `global` object. Do the following

1. In your `package.json`, under `jest` key add `setupFiles` like this
   `"setupFiles": ["test-env.js"]` For example:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [ "<rootDir>/tests/test-env.js" ]
  }
}
```

2. Where the contents on `test-env.js` look like this

```
import $ from 'jquery';
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

Make sure the path to `test-env.js` is correct from your root directory. `<rootDir>` is available in Jest.

Comment: This answer worked for me better than any others. just a note on rootDir, it can be used as follows: "<rootDir>/test-env.js"

my jest setup looked like the folowing:

  "jest": {
    ...
    "setupFiles": ["<rootDir>/test-env.js"]
  }

Comment: In my case this approach not worked. But as soon as I set setupFiles via jest.config.js which I already had - everything became fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jest 27+, node is now the default `testEnvironment`. If you need to use jQuery in jest setup script, make sure to first change the `testEnvironment` back to `jsdom`.

in `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom'
}
```

in `jest.setup.js`:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
global.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;

// If you want to mock bootstrap
global.$.fn.modal = jest.fn(() => $());
global.$.fn.carousel = jest.fn(() => $());
global.$.fn.tooltip = jest.fn(() => $());
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answers didn't work for me. Only this worked: 
Create a file called `setupTests.js` in your src folder and enter this:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
global.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;
```

more info on this solution: [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9706#issuecomment-704004463)