# Using Jest with Jquery

Tags: jestjs

A Jest unit test that tests a React component which calls certain Jquery functions is not passing. I'm receiving the following error: [Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YLi8.png)

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reactjs jest jQuery is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41844947/reactjs-jest-jquery-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

Would require more information about how you ran the test and whether or not you exposed Jquery correctly. This seems to be a problem of not having Jquery either **'imported'** or **'required'** properly in the test file.