# Laravel vite : Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, vite, laravel-vite

I need to use [jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) plugin with Laravel. I have added jQuery and jQuery Steps via NPM
this is my **resources\js\app.js**

```
import './bootstrap';

import jQuery from 'jquery';
window.$ = jQuery;

window.jQuery = jQuery


import 'jquery-steps/build/jquery.steps.min.js';
```

This is my view.

```
@vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])

<script type="module">
    $("#example-basic").steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        autoFocus: true
    });
 </script>
```

But getting this error.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
> at app-0acac567.js:23:13949

Comment: Did you try to move the bootstrap import after the jQuery one?

With the type=module, can you try `jQuery("#example-basic")` instead of `$`, in line with the `import jQuery` line.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for the response but unfortunately didn't work :'(

Comment: How about:

`import {jQuery} from 'jquery';`
`window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;`

There's a lengthy thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41800122/uncaught-referenceerror-jquery-is-not-defined-with-create-react-app?rq=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use it like this in app.js

```
import('jquery-steps/build/jquery.steps.min.js').then(() => {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example-basic').steps({
            headerTag: 'h3',
            bodyTag: 'section',
            transitionEffect: 'slideLeft',
            autoFocus: true
        });
    });
});
```